# Does Chainlink decimal change over time?

Tags: chainlink

I am implementing Chainlink in my contract. Should I request the `decimals()` function periodically, or decimals are static, so I don't have to worry about any decimals change in a specific contract.

Comment: No need to request it periodically, unless you're dealing with a scam token (and probably not even then).

Comment: @goodvibration what about the address for a specific pair, does it stay the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stays the same, it will not change. The only thing to note is that [all pairs have 8 decimals unless it's an ETH pair](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses).

ie: ETH/USD has 8 decimals, and AAVE/ETH will have 18, since the second currency in the pair is ETH.