# Do all Chainlink feeds return prices with 8 decimals of precision?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

It looks like many Chainlink feed aggregators have 8 decimals of precision:

- [ETH/USD](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419), which returns 140330173736 = $1,403.30173736
- [BTC/USD](https://etherscan.io/address/0xF4030086522a5bEEa4988F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c#readContract), which returns 3696759888474 = $36,967.59888474

I found the contracts above on [feeds.chain.link](https://feeds.chain.link/).

Do all Chainlink feed aggregators have 8 decimals of precision?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Non-ETH pairs: 8 decimals

ETH pairs: 18 Decimals

Hence, ETH/USD is a non-ETH pair, so it has 8.
But if it were USD/ETH, it would have 18

[For reference](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90552/does-chainlink-decimal-change-over-time)

EDIT: Each contract has a `decimals` function you can call to see exactly how many it has.

Comment: Maybe I missed it but I didn't see this in the documentation anywhere

Comment: Ideally you call the `decimals` function on the contract itself though, the above is just in general.