# What is the largest number that can be returned from a Chainlink Price Feed?

Tags: gas, oracles, chainlink

Is it safe to assume that chainlink oracles have an upper bound on the price feed, eg it fits into `uint96`, or perhaps a smaller or larger number? It would be great to know the absolute largest number that a chainlink oracle price feed could provide, and potential escaping mechanisms in case this price is exceeded.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Hey Pete, welcome to StackExchange! It is easier for us to answer your questions if you post them separately.

Comment: Also as a side note, this may answer your first question: [Do all Chainlink feeds return prices with 8 decimals of precision?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92508/do-all-chainlink-feeds-return-prices-with-8-decimals-of-precision)

Comment: @Pete, I edited your question so that it's just one. As Paul wrote, the other answer is there.

Comment: I realize now that my question was poorly phrased, because I was looking for a practical upper bound. The largest chainlink price feed number on the Kovan testnet consists of 66 bits, so we have decided to go for a uint88 to accommodate for a factor four million prince increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The largest number can be a number that fits into an `int256`

More info:

Chainlink price feeds can be implemented whatever way works in the future, right now they use an int256 since it *should* cover most use cases, and should be big enough. In the event, a bigger number was needed (which would be a HUGE number), a different price feed would likely be deployed with a solution to that problem.