# How to calculate $10 of ETH without arithmetic overflow

Tags: solidity, chainlink, decimals

I'm using [Chainlink's pricefeed](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/) to get the latest ETHUSD price.

The value returned is `10**8`, i.e. if the price of ETHUSD is `3981.43` then the value will be `398143000000`.

How can I calculate the WEI value of $10 of ETH without causing an arithmetic overflow error?

```
ETHUSD = 398143000000
$10 = 0.002511660383329608 ETH
$10 = 2511660383329608 WEI // How can I get this?
```

Doing the following results in "reverted with panic code 0x11 (Arithmetic operation underflowed or overflowed outside of an unchecked block)":

```
uint256 ethUsdPrice = 398143000000;
uint256 usdTicketPrice = 10;
uint256 ethTicketPrice = ticketPrice*(10**8) / ethUsdPrice*(10**18);
```

I was hoping since I don't divide into decimals this would be OK.

In JavaScript you can see this is the correct calculation:

```
// Dividing down into decimals and then up.
(10 / (398143000000 / 10**8)) * 10**18 = 2511660383329608
// Dividing without decimals.
10*(10**8) / 398143000000*(10**18) = 2511660383329608
```

I'm using Solidity `0.8.7`.

P.S. Seems like there are [similar](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98531/price-conversion-using-chainlink-ethusd-price) questions but they'd result in an overflow too?

Comment: We have that `10^18 wei = (x / 10^8) USD`, where `x = 398143000000` then `10 USD = 10^18 * 10 * 10^8 / x wei = 10^27 / 398143000000 wei = 2511660383329607 wei`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of ethUsdPrice is with 8 decimals, and it equals to 1 ether, it means:

`1 ether = (ethUsdPrice / 10^8) dollars`

We isolate 1 dollar from the equation and get:

`1 dollar = 1 ether * 10^8 / ethUsdPrice`

In Solidity, to maintain accuracy, we always first of all do multiplication and only after doing division - otherwise, we will lose the remainder for the operation. For example 2/3 = 0.

So if that's the value of 1 dollar, we just need to multiply it by usdTicketPrice (10), so your final calculation will be:

`uint256 ethTicketPrice = usdTicketPrice * 1 ether * 10**8 / ethUsdPrice`.