# Cannot get Chainlink Conversion ETH/USD Correct other than 0

Tags: contract-development, chainlink, solidity-0.8.x

I have followed both answers in the following similar question. I some how cannot seem to get a non-zero result. I tried several different ways to modify the below conversion function. Using MockV3Aggregator in hardhat network, test running correctly pre-conversion. Can anyone see my problem? Thank you.

Similar question:
[price conversion using chainlink ETHUSD price](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98531/price-conversion-using-chainlink-ethusd-price)

My code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
int256 public usdPrice; // set to 10 in the constructor  

...

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = s_priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit
        return answer;
    }
    function conversion() public view returns (int) {
        int minRequiredUSD = usdPrice * 10 ** 18;
        int ethPriceUSD = getLatestPrice() * 10 ** 18;
        int minRequiredEther = (minRequiredUSD * 10 ** 18) / ethPriceUSD;
        return minRequiredEther;
    }
    //different attempt lowering division down to a seperate step and etc as to try not to return zero
    function conversionOne() public view returns (int) {
        int answer = getLatestPrice();
        int ethPriceUSDAdj = answer * 10 ** 18;
        int minRequiredUSD = usdPrice * 10 ** 18;
        int minRequiredEther = minRequiredUSD * 10 ** 18;
        int minRequiredEtherDivided = minRequiredEther / ethPriceUSDAdj;
        return minRequiredEtherDivided;
    }

    //different attempt from one of the other recommended answers
    function conversionTwo() public view returns (int) {
        int _price = getLatestPrice() / 10 ** 8
        int minRequiredEtherDivided = usdPrice / _price;
        return minRequiredEtherDivided;
    }

    //function that uses the conversion function:
    function makePayment(address _account, int256 _periods) public payable {
            int conversionPrice = conversion();
            int priceInEth = conversionPrice * _periods;
            require(int(msg.value) >= priceInEth, "not enough ether submitted");
            epochPaid[_account] = epoch + _periods;
    }
```

My test running correctly to know I am returning the correct mock oracle price:

```
                  it("It should return the same value as the mock", async () => {
                      const { Subscription, mockV3Aggregator } = await loadFixture(
                          deployContractAndPrice
                      )
                      const priceConsumerResult = await Subscription.getLatestPrice()
                      const priceFeedResult = (await mockV3Aggregator.latestRoundData()).answer
                      assert.equal(priceConsumerResult.toString(), priceFeedResult.toString())
                  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be the answer as if the returned value was alreadty multiplied by *10**18 you remove it from the first conversion() like:

```
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = s_priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit
        return answer;
    }

    function conversion() public view returns (int256) {
        int256 minRequiredUSD = usdPrice * 10 ** 18;
        int256 ethPriceUSD = getLatestPrice();
        int256 minRequiredEther = (minRequiredUSD * 10 ** 18) / ethPriceUSD;
        return minRequiredEther;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chainlink data feed, if returned data is `xx/USD`, the answer is multiplied by `10 ** 8` like [BTC/USD](https://etherscan.io/address/0xF4030086522a5bEEa4988F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c#readContract)(see price by calling function `latestRoundData` in etherscan UI).

If the returned data is `xx/ETH`, the answer is multiplied by `10 ** 18` like [BTC/ETH](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdeb288F737066589598e9214E782fa5A8eD689e8#readContract)(see price by calling function `latestRoundData` in etherscan UI).